# MS-Access Report fields invisible

Tags: ms-access, report

I need to setup an Access database with some Reports. On the Reports are several fields that are provided by a Query. My problem now is that I have to make some fields invisible if some fields contain special Values. I have Inspections that have been made and if the first field says the inspection is ok then the other fields shouldn't be visible to make the Report more clear.
Due to the regulations of my company I cant use VBA. Is it possible to do that with the expression builder or the embedded Macros?

I am googling now for over 2 Days and I can only find solutions with VBA

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could have an IIf() expression in textbox. What are the 'special values' - just "OK" or is it a yes/no field? `=IIf([yes/no fieldname], Null, [fieldname])`

Comment: Yeah, You will have a Field that says "Yes" for the Visual Inspection to be passed. Therefore the next 6 Answers should not be visble because they are basically containing the same Information. 

Where should I Put that expression? Should I embedd it into the field with the expression builder?

Comment: ````=IIf([OriginalCondition]="No";[InspectionID].[Visible]="No";[InspectionID].[Visible]="Yes")````

This Code sample in the Expressionbuildes threw no Error but also isnt doing anything

Comment: I also tried it to have Subreports to make them Visivle or not with that Expression: 

=IIf([InspectionID]="ITO";[Reports]![AllInspectionsSubLQ2].[Visible]="No";[Reports]![AllInspectionsSubLQ2].[Visible]="Yes")

but it is also not working

Comment: Can't set Visible property with ControlSource expression.  Expression either shows data or is Null. Look at my example again. However, possibly that is not what you want. What do you mean by 'next 6 answers' - 6 fields or 6 records? If you don't want data to repeat in successive records, use textbox HideDuplicates property setting, no VBA.

Comment: I have a Inspection made with 7 Points, not all with yes or no answers
1. Everything ok - yes 
2. Top ok - yes
3. Stairs working - yes 
4.  left ok - yes 
5. right ok - yes  
6. middle ok - yes

So if the person who made the inspection says Yes on everything ok, I dont want to have the other entries shown on the report. I have 7 other sectors so if I can make this  work I can produce a report that extends the more things aren't ok but keeps beeing short if everything is allright.